# Shinydashboard: Incorrect vertical rendering of items in tabbox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using `shinydashboards tabboxes` and having issues with the vertical alignment of `fluidrows` within the `tabbox` such that a button renders on top of my plot.

The first tab in the `tabbox` contains a plot and download button each in their own fluidRow, the second tab contains a `datatable` and download button, each in their own fluidRow. The plot is a facet_grid, and to make it visible, I specified the height of the plot in my server. The plot renders correctly, but the `UI` does not seem to respond to the specified height when rendering the button and renders the button on top of the plot.

I also specify the height of the datatable object for the data tab in the server using;
`renderDataTable(options = list(scrollY = "400px"){}`.

In this case, the button in the data tab renders in the correct vertical position below the data table.

Below is a reproducible example of the dashboard structure. Any input on why the button in the graph tab is rendering on top of the plot would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)

# load data in long format
dat <- mtcars
dat <- dat %>%
  select(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "wt")) %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", cyl, disp, drat, wt )


#############################
#The dashboard
############################

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Title", titleWidth = 450)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Model", icon = icon("dashboard"), tabName = "model")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(

    #====================================
    tabItem(tabName = "model",
            #===========
          fluidRow(
                           tabBox(side="left",
                                  width = 8,
                                  height = "700px",
                                  title = "",
                                  id = "model_tab",
                                  tabPanel("Graph",
                                           column(width = 12,
                                                    fluidRow(
                                                      plotOutput("plot")
                                                      ), # close fluidRow
                                                    fluidRow(
                                                      downloadButton("plot_download")
                                                      )  #close fluidRow
                                                ) #close column
                                          ),   #close tabPanel

                                  tabPanel("Data",
                                             column(width = 12,
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 DT::dataTableOutput("data", 
                                                                   height = "350px")
                                                 ), #close fluidRow
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 downloadButton("data_download")
                                                ) # close fluidRow
                                             ) #close column
                                          ) # close tabPabel
                           ), # close tabBox

            #=========== 
            sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                         align = "left",

                         title = "User controls",
                         color = "fuchsia", 
                         solidHeader = TRUE, 

                         sliderInput("mpg",
                                "mpg",
                                min = 1,
                                max = 100,
                                value = 10),


                         sliderInput("cyl",
                                        "cyl",
                                        min = 5,
                                        max = 50,
                                        value = 10),


                         sliderInput("disp",
                                        "disp",
                                        min = 5,
                                        max = 50,
                                        value = 10),


                         sliderInput("drat",
                                        "drat",
                                        min = 100,
                                        max = 300,
                                        value = 155),



                         dateRangeInput("date_range", 
                                   "Date range", 
                                   start=as.Date('2020-04-01') , 
                                   end = as.Date('2025-03-01'),
                                   format = "yyyy-mm-dd")#,


          )  #close sidebarpanel
          ) #close fluidRow
        )  #close tabItem
  ) #close tabItems
)  #close dashboardBody

#################################################
ui <- dashboardPage(header, 
                    sidebar, 
                    body, 
                    skin= "purple")
#################################################

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {




   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     plt <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=value, y=mpg))+
       geom_point()+
       facet_grid(rows=vars(unique(dat$key)))
     plt

   plt
  }, height = 600)





  output$plot_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      print(plotInput())
      dev.off()
    })


  output$data <- renderDataTable(options = list(scrollY = "400px"), {
    dat
  })

  output$HOW_data_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(dat, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

  }


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify your height in the ui like this `plotOutput("plot", height = "600px")` it should render correctly